# Catch a Specific OSError Exception in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, error-handling, try-except

In Python 3, how can we catch a specific `OSError` exception?

My current code catches all `OSError`, but only `OSError: [Errno 12]` needs to be caught.

```
try:
    foo()
except OSError as e:
    print('Caught OSError: [Errno12]')
```

The full error message is:

> Caught OSError: [Errno12] Cannot allocate memory

How can we let Python catch only the `Errno12` variant of `OSError`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `errno` attribute of the [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError). For an error:

```
>>> raise OSError(12, 'Some Error')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-8a046f16ebb6>", line 1, in <module>
    raise OSError(12, 'Some Error')

OSError: [Errno 12] Some Error
```

Use the following:

```
try:
    raise OSError(12, 'Some Error')
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == 12:
        print('OSError no. 12 caught')
    else:
        raise

# Output:
# OSError: [Errno 12] Some Error
```

Comment: Great answer, but probably they want to "raise" and not "continue" if it's not Errno12, thus effectively only catching Errno12.

Comment: @TamirIlan Edited. Of course OP can decide what they want to do when the condition does not meet.

Answer (score 9):

For clarity, and because some error numbers can differ between platforms (see e.g. [this](http://www.ioplex.com/%7Emiallen/errcmpp.html) comparison), I would recommend using the [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/errno.html) module in order to catch the specific type of OSError in a cross-platform way:

```
try:
    # Code that might fail...
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOMEM:
        # Handle ENOMEM case...
    else:
        raise
```

You can use the dictionary `errno.errorcode` to find the name of a specific error code in the `errno` module:

```
>>> errno.errorcode[12]
'ENOMEM'
```

Note that error number 12 specifically seems to be the same across most platforms, but many others differ.